# invalid fastbin entry (free) on jdk1.7.0_79_oracle//bin/java

Tags: java, memory, crash, heap-memory

```
*** Error in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79_oracle//bin/java': invalid fastbin entry (free): 0x00007fb76e115f50 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d1fd)[0x7fb848ddb1fd]
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79_oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so(+0x8479)[0x7fb8477d4479]
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79_oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so(+0x9682)[0x7fb8477d5682]
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79_oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so(VerifyClassForMajorVersion+0x635)[0x7fb8477d6b05]
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79_oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(+0x987769)[0x7fb84886b769]
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79_oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(+0x995ee1)[0x7fb848879ee1]
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79_oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(+0x5bde4d)[0x7fb8484a1e4d]
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79_oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JVM_GetClassDeclaredConstructors+0x1b7)[0x7fb8485693f7]
[0x7fb84418cd98]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:00 2359313                            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79_oracle/bin/java
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 08:00 2359313                            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79_oracle/bin/java
0091e000-00e17000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
...
```

It keeps going, thousands of lines from here.

I've experienced this error some months ago and now it happened again. The application just stopped answering and this error was there when I checked it out. It just freezes for no apparent reason.

I don't know if it's that a big deal, but one thing I noticed is the `catalina.out` file with 1.3GB.

Does anyone know if that's a bug or the application might be causing this crash?